# Building Xcode Project from Unity gets "undefined symbol in arm64" error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, arm64

I've developed a game for Android on Unity. And now I'm trying to port it for iOS.

Since this is my first time to use Mac for any mean of development, building Xcode project gave me tons of problems.

I've googled and solved pretty many problems but now I'm stuck with these errors.

On the process of building, after compiling tons of sources, the linking process spits out few warning messages about libiPhone-lib.a.

And after like 2-300 warning messages about google play game services, build fails with following errors.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGClearcutLogger.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in gpg(GIPNetworkImage.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

When I googled about it, I found that it seems like something about arm64 support of google play game service but I have used the latest google play game service package. I have set scripting backend on Unity to IL2CPP, and target architecture to Universal(both armv7 and arm64). Now I have no Idea to resolve these errors.

I'm using Unity 5.3.4p3 and Xcode 8.2beta.

Thank you.

Comment: best solution is remove Google Play Service from Unity and then export it to iOS.

Comment: To disable the Google Play Game Services in the iOS build, open the iOS player settings. Then in the "Other Settings" panel, find the entry named "Scripting Define Symbol" and add a symbol named: NO_GPGS (case sensitive).